# Web Inspector on Mac is empty when connected to iPad

Tags: macos, ipad, safari

I am struggling to use the Web Inspector on my Mac to inspect the webpage on my iPad.  This is what I have tried so far:

- I have turned on web inspector on my iPad.
- I have checked that cookies are enabled on both the Mac and the iPad.
- I have connected my iPad up to my Mac with a cable.
- On the Mac, under the develop menu I can see my iPad - when I hover
  the mouse over the visible tab, the webpage on my iPad highlights with blue. Clicking that brings up the Web Inspector on my Mac.
- When I hit refresh in the Web Inspector on my Mac, the page on my
  iPad refreshes.

There is obviously a connection between my iPad and my Mac.

However, the rest of the Web Inspector on my Mac seems empty.

The Elements tab is empty.  The Network tab shows an empty list (headers only), even after a refresh.  The Resources tab is empty.  The Timelines tab is empty.  The Debugger tab is empty and shows no sources.  The Storage tab is empty.  And the Console tab shows nothing, despite numerous calls to console.log from my webpage on the iPad.

I have also tried opening a private browsing window on my Mac and tried connecting to my iPad via the Web Inspector from there.  Still no joy.

I am using Safari version 11.1.1 on my Mac.  I am unsure how to check the version number of Safari on my iPad.  I am an experienced Windows user but have limited experience with Macs.  Please let me know if there is any further information that I could provide.

Can anyone help me in getting the Web Inspector to work properly between my Mac and my iPad?  Many thanks.